# Advice on how to create a view in Redshift based on the following:

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following table structure

```
JUR SDATE       EDATE       DESC
NYC 2019-04-06  2019-04-22  Term 1  USA
NYC 2019-06-29  2019-07-14  Term 2  USA
NYC 2019-09-21  2019-10-07  Term 3  USA
NYC 2019-12-14  2020-01-27  Term 4  USA
CAL 2019-04-13  2019-04-29  Term 1  USA
CAL 2019-09-28  2019-10-13  Term 3  USA
CAL 2019-12-19  2020-01-28  Term 4  USA
DPR 2019-05-06  2019-05-29  Term 1  COL
```

I need to create a view to return the following Boolean values parsing a date between start and end?

```
isNYCtermdate
isCALtermdate 
isDPRtermdate
```

Comment: And what is the logic for the flags?  What result set do you want?

Comment: Just a Y or N if the value falls between the dates.

Comment: If *what* value falls between *what* dates?

Comment: if the value falls in between the dates, it should return a Y and if not, then a N

Comment: Do you want to pass in an arbitrary date and and find which term date ranges it falls in? If so you need to build a _function_, not a view.